# How do I create a customized CD that doesn't display any installation screens?

Tags: installation, live-cd, customization, iso

I would like to create customized Ubuntu installation CD.

Here is what I want a customized Ubuntu Installation CD to do:

1. Do not display any Installation Screens of Ubuntu.
2. Manually, set default values of all Installation Screens (such as Keybord, timezone, login username and password, partitions etc) in source code (ubuntu installation code, may be in some configuration files)
3. Install required packages and my project.

How could I change Ubuntu installation code and what changes need to apply ?

I have read [customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd) but there is no information for removing Installation Screens and their default settings.Please, let me know, if I missed something. also, I would like to know, could it be possible to apply similar changes (from that questions) with Ubuntu installation changes ?

Thanks :)

**[EDIT] : Problem when tried pressed and initrd method**

I have tried pressed file and initrd method as per the [document](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/preseed-intro.html). but now I've stuck on a step.

here, what I did:

1) Used default preseed file (given in document)

2) Used Ubuntu 10.04 iso for testing

3) Follow the link [How to install Ubuntu Linux from USB Stick](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-from-usb-stick.html) to make USB bootable for installing ubuntu 10.04.

4) now, I have bootable USB.

but on installation, System could not found iso from the USB and it stops working.

Could anyone suggest, correct step by step method (or links) for the same ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'd have a look into this http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/
I haven't used it myself but I've hear positive things.

Comment: If i understand correctly, what you have to do is to manually edit the Ubiquity installer, there is a thread on the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: @Smithamax, thanks for the link, I think it would be used for taking backup of ubuntu on another machine but could not possible to remove installation screens, using it. let me correct if anything missing.

Comment: @Uri Herrera, thanks for the suggestion, I will check for Ubiquity installer. but as per Emmet Hikory said "Pressed" seems more promising. I need to look more for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decide many of the answers to the installer questions in advance, using [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/installation-guide/amd64/apb.html). If the answer is decided in advance, the installer should not prompt the user for input.

If you are working from a live image, to include additional software, you may include additional software in the squashfs.

Comment: Please, check edited block, I have some problem with Installation.
If you could help.